# Android stock SMS App preview doing prefetching of a link embedded in a text message before the user clicks on it?

Tags: sms

Another hair-pulling exercise.  I am generating a link in a text message and when the user clicks on it then it would call the page, and take some action.  Simple!  But in the stock Android messages app (and perhaps others) it would appear that as soon as the message comes in it opens the link (effectively clicks on it like a user would = does a preview fetch?) even before there is an alert to the user.  When the user then clicks on the link it is called a second time but that fails because the first call set a flag in a DB that the second call trips over.  Is there some mechanism to programmatically thwart previews? Or detect that it is a preview?

Comment: Post some codes to help us understand what you have done

Comment: This isn't an issue with code. It is an operational question that affects code design

Comment: In any event it appears to be a real phenomenon and there is nothing that can be done about it as near as I can tell. So after redesigning my code this now serves as more of a heads-up than a question.

Comment: One GLARING example.  If you send a text with a link and want to keep track of whether the user clicks on the link, you can no longer be certain that the user actually clicked on the link because the text app fetched the page once already without the user even knowing.  This means you have to add other measures in the page you serve to entice a user to interact with it so that you can really tell if they clicked on the text link - unless of course the prefetch offers some sort of robotag that be used to distinguish it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 4 years + late. I have this same issue! My solution was to do a double redirect. The sms pre fetch only loads the main url and does not follow any redirects. So instead of marking your database as a page view based on the main url, create a shorten url that redirects to a 2nd url. Then have that 2nd url mark the database as a clicked page view.

This way when the sms texting app pre fetches the webpage, nothing is tracked because that page has no tracking associated with it. It is the redirect url that does the tracking, which the sms app will not load because it will not follow redirects. Hope this helps.